# Aurelia app not deploying to Azure correctly

Tags: azure, aurelia, jspm

I've been following [this](http://www.webnotwar.ca/opensource/azure-web-app-continuous-integration-with-aurelia-and-github/) tutorial to try get my aurelia app deployed on Azure.

Here is my `deploy.cmd` script:

```
@if "%SCM_TRACE_LEVEL%" NEQ "4" @echo off

:: ----------------------
:: KUDU Deployment Script
:: Version: 1.0.13
:: ----------------------

:: Prerequisites
:: -------------

:: Verify node.js installed
where node 2>nul >nul
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
  echo Missing node.js executable, please install node.js, if already installed make sure it can be reached from current environment.
  goto error
)

:: Setup
:: -----

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

SET ARTIFACTS=%~dp0%..\artifacts

IF NOT DEFINED DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE (
  SET DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE=%~dp0%.
)

IF NOT DEFINED DEPLOYMENT_TARGET (
  SET DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=%ARTIFACTS%\wwwroot
)

IF NOT DEFINED NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH (
  SET NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH=%ARTIFACTS%\manifest

  IF NOT DEFINED PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH (
    SET PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH=%ARTIFACTS%\manifest
  )
)

IF NOT DEFINED KUDU_SYNC_CMD (
  :: Install kudu sync
  echo Installing Kudu Sync
  call npm install kudusync -g --silent
  IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error

  :: Locally just running "kuduSync" would also work
  SET KUDU_SYNC_CMD=%appdata%\npm\kuduSync.cmd
)

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: Deployment
:: ----------

echo Handling Aurelia App deployment.

:: 1. Install JSPM packages and then bundle resources.
echo pushd "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%"
pushd "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%"

echo "1. npm install"
call npm install

echo "2. npm install jspm -g"
call npm install jspm -g

echo "3. jspm install -y"
call jspm install -y

echo "4. gulp bundle"
call gulp bundle

echo "5. popd"
popd

:: 2. Set files for Kudu not to copy to the Azure Web App.
SET KUDU_IGNORE=.deployment;.editorconfig;.gitignore;.npmignore;build;custom_typings;doc;node_modules;test;typings;aurelia.protractor.js;deploy.cmd;gulpfile.js;karma.conf.js;package.json;protractor.conf.js;README.md;tsconfig.json;tslint.json;typings.json;wallaby.js

:: 3. KuduSync
IF /I "%IN_PLACE_DEPLOYMENT%" NEQ "1" (
  call :ExecuteCmd "%KUDU_SYNC_CMD%" -v 50 -f "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%" -t "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%" -n "%NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH%" -p "%PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH%" -i "%KUDU_IGNORE%"
  IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
)

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
goto end

:: Execute command routine that will echo out when error
:ExecuteCmd
setlocal
set _CMD_=%*
call %_CMD_%
if "%ERRORLEVEL%" NEQ "0" echo Failed exitCode=%ERRORLEVEL%, command=%_CMD_%
exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%

:error
endlocal
echo An error has occurred during web site deployment.
call :exitSetErrorLevel
call :exitFromFunction 2>nul

:exitSetErrorLevel
exit /b 1

:exitFromFunction
()

:end
endlocal
echo Finished successfully.
```

When I run `deploy.cmd` locally, it builds to `../artifacts/wwwroot`.

I can verify it works by starting `artifacts\wwwroot>python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000`.

**I can see my app working at** `127.0.0.1:8000`.

However, when I try to attach my bitbucket repo to an azure webapp (following the steps in the tutorial), it appears to deploy okay but when I navigate to the page, I have the following errors:

```
bluebird.min.js:33 Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://arianeonlineui.azurewebsites.net/dist/main.js
    Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://xxx.azurewebsites.net/dist/main.js
    Error loading http://xxx.azurewebsites.net/dist/main.js
r @ bluebird.min.js:33
i._settlePromiseFromHandler @ bluebird.min.js:32
i._settlePromise @ bluebird.min.js:32
i._settlePromise0 @ bluebird.min.js:32
i._settlePromises @ bluebird.min.js:32
r._drainQueue @ bluebird.min.js:31
r._drainQueues @ bluebird.min.js:31
drainQueues @ bluebird.min.js:31
```

[image]

Is this because the jspm modules are not being installed? Can anybody help me diagnose or resolve the issue?

**Edit**
Output from deployment script:

```
Command: deploy.cmd
Handling Aurelia App deployment.
pushd "D:\home\site\repository"
"1. npm install"
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/aurelia-protractor-plugin
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/gulp-sourcemaps
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/protractor
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/gulp-sourcemaps
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/protractor
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/aurelia-protractor-plugin
npm WARN engine protractor@4.0.14: wanted: {"node":">=4.2.x"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.28","npm":"1.4.9"})
npm WARN engine gulp-sourcemaps@2.6.0: wanted: {"node":">=4"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.28","npm":"1.4.9"})
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/types/selenium-webdriver
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/convert-source-map
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/css
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/detect-newline
...
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/gulp-sourcemaps/identity-map
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/gulp-sourcemaps/map-sources
npm ERR! 404 Not Found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 'types/selenium-webdriver' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'aurelia-protractor-plugin'
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, or http url, or git url.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "node" "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\npm\\1.4.9\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! cwd D:\home\site\repository
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.28
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9
npm ERR! code E404
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/adm-zip
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/glob
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/chalk
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jasmine
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jasminewd2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/selenium-webdriver
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/optimist
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/saucelabs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/source-map-support
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/q
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/webdriver-manager
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/types/jasmine
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/types/node
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/types/q
npm ERR! TypeError: Cannot read property '2.53.37' of undefined
npm ERR!     at D:\Program Files (x86)\npm\1.4.9\node_modules\npm\lib\cache.js:844:27
npm ERR!     at RegClient.get_ (D:\Program Files (x86)\npm\1.4.9\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\get.js:111:14)
npm ERR!     at RegClient.<anonymous> (D:\Program Files (x86)\npm\1.4.9\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\get.js:47:12)
npm ERR!     at fs.js:266:14
npm ERR!     at D:\Program Files (x86)\npm\1.4.9\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:105:5
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "node" "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\npm\\1.4.9\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! cwd D:\home\site\repository
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.28
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9
npm ERR! type non_object_property_load
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/adm-zip
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/chalk
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/glob
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/jasminewd2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/selenium-webdriver
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/jasmine
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/saucelabs
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/source-map-support
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/optimist
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/q
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/webdriver-manager
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/types/jasmine
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/types/node
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/types/q
"2. npm install jspm -g"
npmnpm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jspm
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/jspm
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jspm-github
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/liftoff
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/core-js
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jspm-npm
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jspm-registry
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ncp
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch
...
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/traceur
npm WARN engine rsvp@3.5.0: wanted: {"node":"0.12.* || 4.* || 6.* || 7.*"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.28","npm":"1.4.9"})
npm WARN engine request@2.81.0: wanted: {"node":">= 4"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.28","npm":"1.4.9"})
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/escape-string-regexp

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/is-typedarray
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/http-signature
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/json-stringify-safe
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/hawk
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/isstream
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/oauth-sign
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/qs
....
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/is-windows
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/array-unique
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/expand-brackets
npm WARN engine har-validator@4.2.1: wanted: {"node":">=4"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.28","npm":"1.4.9"})
npm WARN engine form-data@2.1.4: wanted: {"node":">= 0.12"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.28","npm":"1.4.9"})
npm WARN engine hawk@3.1.3: wanted: {"node":">=0.10.32"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.28","npm":"1.4.9"})
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/global-prefix
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/braces
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/extglob
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/filename-regex
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/kind-of
...
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/amdefine
D:\local\AppData\npm\jspm -> D:\local\AppData\npm\node_modules\jspm\jspm.js
jspm@0.16.53 D:\local\AppData\npm\node_modules\jspm
├── graceful-fs@4.1.11
├── semver@5.3.0
├── ncp@2.0.0
├── minimatch@3.0.4 (brace-expansion@1.1.8)
├── chalk@1.1.3 (escape-string-regexp@1.0.5, supports-color@2.0.0, ansi-styles@2.2.1, has-ansi@2.0.0, strip-ansi@3.0.1)
├── glob@6.0.4 (path-is-absolute@1.0.1, inherits@2.0.3, inflight@1.0.6, once@1.4.0)
├── mkdirp@0.5.1 (minimist@0.0.8)
├── proper-lockfile@1.2.0 (err-code@1.1.2, retry@0.10.1, extend@3.0.1)
├── jspm-registry@0.4.4 (semver@4.3.6)
├── rimraf@2.6.1 (glob@7.1.2)
├── jspm-github@0.13.18 (netrc@0.1.4, expand-tilde@1.2.2, which@1.2.14, yauzl@2.8.0, tar@2.2.1)
├── rsvp@3.5.0
├── liftoff@2.3.0 (lodash.isstring@4.0.1, lodash.isplainobject@4.0.6, rechoir@0.6.2, flagged-respawn@0.3.2, extend@3.0.1, lodash.mapvalues@4.6.0, fined@1.1.0, resolve@1.3.3, findup-sync@0.4.3)
├── jspm-npm@0.26.13 (buffer-peek-stream@1.0.1, which@1.2.14, glob@5.0.15, tar@1.0.3, resolve@1.3.3)
├─��� systemjs@0.19.46 (when@3.7.8)
├── uglify-js@2.8.29 (uglify-to-browserify@1.0.2, yargs@3.10.0, source-map@0.5.6)
├── request@2.81.0 (is-typedarray@1.0.0, aws-sign2@0.6.0, oauth-sign@0.8.2, forever-agent@0.6.1, caseless@0.12.0, tunnel-agent@0.6.0, stringstream@0.0.5, isstream@0.1.2, json-stringify-safe@5.0.1, safe-buffer@5.1.1, performance-now@0.2.0, extend@3.0.1, aws4@1.6.0, uuid@3.1.0, combined-stream@1.0.5, qs@6.4.0, form-data@2.1.4, mime-types@2.1.15, tough-cookie@2.3.2, hawk@3.1.3, http-signature@1.1.1, har-validator@4.2.1)
├── core-js@1.2.7
├── traceur@0.0.105 (commander@2.9.0, semver@4.3.6, glob@5.0.15, source-map-support@0.2.10)
└── systemjs-builder@0.15.36 (data-uri-to-buffer@0.0.4, babel-plugin-transform-system-register@0.0.1, glob@7.1.2, bluebird@3.5.0, source-map@0.5.6, uglify-js@2.7.5, rollup@0.36.4, es6-template-strings@2.0.1, babel-plugin-transform-cjs-system-wrapper@0.3.0, babel-core@6.25.0, babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-systemjs@6.24.1, babel-plugin-transform-global-system-wrapper@0.0.1)
"3. jspm install -y"
     Looking up npm:aurelia-animator-css
     Looking up npm:aurelia-bootstrapper
     Looking up npm:aurelia-dialog
     Looking up npm:aurelia-fetch-client
     Looking up npm:aurelia-framework
     Looking up npm:aurelia-history-browser
     Looking up npm:aurelia-loader-default
     Looking up npm:aurelia-logging-console
     Looking up npm:aurelia-pal-browser
     Looking up npm:aurelia-polyfills
     Looking up npm:aurelia-router
     Looking up npm:aurelia-templating-binding
     Looking up npm:aurelia-templating-resources
     Looking up npm:aurelia-templating-router
     Looking up npm:bluebird
     Looking up npm:font-awesome
     Looking up npm:jquery
     Creating registry cache...
     Looking up github:twbs/bootstrap
     Looking up github:systemjs/plugin-text
     Looking up github:github/fetch
     Downloading npm:aurelia-fetch-client@1.1.2
     Downloading npm:aurelia-animator-css@1.0.2
     Downloading npm:aurelia-bootstrapper@1.0.1
     Downloading npm:aurelia-logging-console@1.0.0
     Downloading npm:aurelia-dialog@1.0.0-rc.1.0.3
     Downloading npm:aurelia-framework@1.1.2
     Downloading npm:aurelia-loader-default@1.0.2
     Downloading npm:aurelia-history-browser@1.0.0
     Downloading npm:aurelia-pal-browser@1.2.1
     Downloading npm:aurelia-polyfills@1.2.1
     Looking up npm:aurelia-metadata
     Looking up npm:aurelia-pal
     Looking up npm:aurelia-templating
     Looking up npm:aurelia-event-aggregator
     Looking up npm:aurelia-history
     Looking up npm:aurelia-logging
     Looking up npm:aurelia-dependency-injection
     Looking up npm:aurelia-binding
     Looking up npm:aurelia-loader
     Looking up npm:aurelia-path
     Looking up npm:aurelia-task-queue
     Downloading npm:aurelia-router@1.3.0
     Downloading npm:aurelia-templating-binding@1.3.0
     Downloading npm:aurelia-templating-router@1.1.0
     Downloading npm:aurelia-templating-resources@1.4.0
     Downloading github:systemjs/plugin-text@0.0.8
     Downloading github:github/fetch@1.1.1
     Looking up npm:aurelia-route-recognizer
     Downloading npm:bluebird@3.4.1
     Downloading npm:font-awesome@4.6.3
     Downloading npm:jquery@2.2.4
     Downloading github:twbs/bootstrap@3.3.7
     Downloading npm:aurelia-event-aggregator@1.0.1
     Downloading npm:aurelia-metadata@1.0.3
     Downloading npm:aurelia-pal@1.3.0
     Downloading npm:aurelia-logging@1.3.1
     Downloading npm:aurelia-loader@1.0.0
     Downloading npm:aurelia-templating@1.4.2
     Downloading npm:aurelia-dependency-injection@1.3.1
     Downloading npm:aurelia-path@1.1.1
     Downloading npm:aurelia-route-recognizer@1.1.0
     Downloading npm:aurelia-history@1.0.0
     Downloading npm:aurelia-binding@1.2.1
     Downloading npm:aurelia-task-queue@1.2.0
     Looking up github:systemjs/plugin-css
     Downloading github:systemjs/plugin-css@0.1.35
ok   Installed text as github:systemjs/plugin-text@^0.0.8 (0.0.8)
ok   Installed fetch as github:github/fetch@^1.0.0 (1.1.1)
ok   Installed npm:aurelia-logging-console@^1.0.0 (1.0.0)
ok   Installed npm:aurelia-pal-browser@^1.0.0 (1.2.1)
ok   Installed npm:aurelia-pal@^1.0.0 (1.3.0)
ok   Installed npm:aurelia-pal@^1.1.0 (1.3.0)
ok   Installed npm:aurelia-pal@^1.3.0 (1.3.0)
ok   Installed npm:aurelia-history@^1.0.0 (1.0.0)
ok   Installed npm:aurelia-event-aggregator@^1.0.0 (1.0.1)
ok   Installed npm:aurelia-loader-default@^1.0.0 (1.0.2)
ok   Installed npm:aurelia-logging@^1.0.0 (1.3.1)
ok   Installed npm:aurelia-templating-binding@^1.0.0 (1.3.0)
ok   Installed npm:aurelia-polyfills@^1.0.0 (1.2.1)
ok   Installed npm:aurelia-path@^1.0.0 (1.1.1)
ok   Installed npm:aurelia-task-queue@^1.0.0 (1.2.0)
ok   Installed npm:aurelia-task-queue@^1.1.0 (1.2.0)
ok   Installed npm:aurelia-templating-router@^1.0.0 (1.1.0)
ok   Installed npm:aurelia-history-browser@^1.0.0 (1.0.0)
ok   Installed npm:aurelia-loader@^1.0.0 (1.0.0)
ok   Installed npm:aurelia-metadata@^1.0.0 (1.0.3)
ok   Installed aurelia-fetch-client as npm:aurelia-fetch-client@^1.0.0 (1.1.2)
ok   Installed bluebird as npm:bluebird@3.4.1 (3.4.1)
ok   Installed npm:aurelia-route-recognizer@^1.0.0 (1.1.0)
ok   Installed npm:aurelia-dependency-injection@^1.0.0 (1.3.1)
ok   Installed npm:aurelia-router@^1.0.1 (1.3.0)
ok   Installed aurelia-router as npm:aurelia-router@^1.0.0 (1.3.0)
ok   Installed npm:jquery (2.2.4)
ok   Installed jquery as npm:jquery@^2.2.4 (2.2.4)
ok   Installed bootstrap as github:twbs/bootstrap@^3.3.6 (3.3.7)
ok   Installed npm:aurelia-framework@^1.0.0 (1.1.2)
ok   Installed npm:aurelia-templating-resources@^1.0.0 (1.4.0)
ok   Installed npm:aurelia-templating@^1.0.0 (1.4.2)
ok   Installed npm:aurelia-templating@^1.3.0 (1.4.2)
ok   Installed github:systemjs/plugin-css@0.1 (0.1.35)
ok   Installed font-awesome as npm:font-awesome@4.6.3 (4.6.3)
ok   Installed npm:aurelia-binding@^1.0.0 (1.2.1)
ok   Installed npm:aurelia-binding@^1.1.0 (1.2.1)
ok   Installed npm:aurelia-binding@^1.0.9 (1.2.1)
ok   Installed aurelia-bootstrapper as npm:aurelia-bootstrapper@^1.0.0 (1.0.1)
ok   Installed aurelia-animator-css as npm:aurelia-animator-css@^1.0.0 (1.0.2)
ok   Installed aurelia-dialog as npm:aurelia-dialog@^1.0.0-beta.3.0.1 (1.0.0-rc.1.0.3)
ok   Install tree has no forks.
     Looking up loader files...
       system.js
       system-csp-production.js
       system.js.map
       system-csp-production.src.js
       system.src.js
       system-csp-production.js.map
       system-polyfills.src.js
       system-polyfills.js
       system-polyfills.js.map

     Using loader versions:
       systemjs@0.19.46
ok   Loader files downloaded successfully

"4. gulp bundle"

Error: Cannot find module 'babel-runtime/core-js/get-iterator'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\repository\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\index.js:6:21)
"5. popd"
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\repository\node_modules\babel-core\lib\api\node.js:6:13)
KuduSync.NET from: 'D:\home\site\repository' to: 'D:\home\site\wwwroot'
Copying file: 'config.js'
Copying file: '.git\config'
Copying file: '.git\FETCH_HEAD'
Copying file: '.git\HEAD'
Copying file: '.git\index'
Copying file: '.git\logs\HEAD'
Copying file: '.git\logs\refs\heads\develop'
Copying file: '.git\logs\refs\remotes\origin\develop'
Copying file: '.git\objects\79\c18b5ceac04b750b761315b839835b252a1c25'
Copying file: '.git\objects\a4\68a04f8f373685615b00b04bd47f27edcafb7e'
Copying file: '.git\objects\pack\pack-f9eaca8d582f9ac870c49c3642ec3ba52bdce331.pack'
Copying file: '.git\refs\heads\develop'
Copying file: '.git\refs\remotes\origin\develop'
Copying file: 'jspm_packages\.dependencies.json'
Copying file: 'jspm_packages\.loaderversions'
Copying file: 'jspm_packages\system-csp-production.js'
Copying file: 'jspm_packages\system-csp-production.js.map'
Copying file: 'jspm_packages\system-csp-production.src.js'
Copying file: 'jspm_packages\system-polyfills.js'
Copying file: 'jspm_packages\system-polyfills.js.map'
Copying file: 'jspm_packages\system-polyfills.src.js'
Copying file: 'jspm_packages\system.js'
Copying file: 'jspm_packages\system.js.map'
Copying file: 'jspm_packages\system.src.js'
Copying file: 'jspm_packages\github\github\fetch@1.1.1.js'
Copying file: 'jspm_packages\github\github\fetch@1.1.1\.jshintrc'
Copying file: 'jspm_packages\github\github\fetch@1.1.1\.jspm-hash'
Copying file: 'jspm_packages\github\github\fetch@1.1.1\.senv'
Copying file: 'jspm_packages\github\github\fetch@1.1.1\.travis.yml'
Copying file: 'jspm_packages\github\github\fetch@1.1.1\bower.json'
Copying file: 'jspm_packages\github\github\fetch@1.1.1\fetch.js'
Copying file: 'jspm_packages\github\github\fetch@1.1.1\LICENSE'
Copying file: 'jspm_packages\github\github\fetch@1.1.1\MAINTAINING.md'
Copying file: 'jspm_packages\github\github\fetch@1.1.1\Makefile'
Copying file: 'jspm_packages\github\github\fetch@1.1.1\examples\index.html'
Copying file: 'jspm_packages\github\github\fetch@1.1.1\script\phantomjs'
Copying file: 'jspm_packages\github\github\fetch@1.1.1\script\saucelabs'
Copying file: 'jspm_packages\github\github\fetch@1.1.1\script\saucelabs-api'
Copying file: 'jspm_packages\github\github\fetch@1.1.1\script\server'
Copying file: 'jspm_packages\github\systemjs\plugin-css@0.1.35.js'
Copying file: 'jspm_packages\github\systemjs\plugin-text@0.0.8.js'
Copying file: 'jspm_packages\github\systemjs\plugin-css@0.1.35\.jspm-hash'
Copying file: 'jspm_packages\github\systemjs\plugin-css@0.1.35\css-plugin-base-builder.js'
Copying file: 'jspm_packages\github\systemjs\plugin-css@0.1.35\css-plugin-base.js'
Copying file: 'jspm_packages\github\systemjs\plugin-css@0.1.35\css.js'
Copying file: 'jspm_packages\github\systemjs\plugin-css@0.1.35\LICENSE'
Copying file: 'jspm_packages\github\systemjs\plugin-css@0.1.35\postcss-bundle.js'
Copying file: 'jspm_packages\github\systemjs\plugin-css@0.1.35\build-post-css\jspm.config.js'
Copying file: 'jspm_packages\github\systemjs\plugin-css@0.1.35\build-post-css\postcss-bundle.js'
Omitting next output lines...
Finished successfully.
```

The interesting section here I think is:

```
"4. gulp bundle"

Error: Cannot find module 'babel-runtime/core-js/get-iterator'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\repository\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\index.js:6:21)
"5. popd"
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\repository\node_modules\babel-core\lib\api\node.js:6:13)
KuduSync.NET from: 'D:\home\site\repository' to: 'D:\home\site\wwwroot'
```

Comment: The deployment log under `Deployment options` blade in the Azure Portal should tell you how the jspm stuff went. Probably not so great.

Comment: Also, should't you be doing something like `node node_modules\jspm\jspm.js install -y` since jspm isn't installed globally? gulp *is* installed globally in App Service, so that line should be fine.

Comment: Hey - I've updated my script (just to identify each call being executed) and added the output at the bottom - would you mind taking a quick look?

Comment: I think the issue illustrated in the logs is `Error: Cannot find module 'babel-runtime/core-js/get-iterator'`....